# Decimal point (.) as separator in java application and comma (,) separator in Oracle database

Tags: java, database, decimal, locale

The problem is not so easy to fix.

1. With the following code,

   ```
   Locale.setDefault(new Locale("fr", "FR"));
   ```

   the format of a float is 123 456,45 and the date format is 30 mars 2015.
2. With the following code,

   ```
   Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
   ```

   the format of a float is 123,456.45 and the date format is Mar 30, 2015.

How can I set the default `Locale` to have 123,456.45 and 30 mars 2015 ? I mean english format for the float and french format for the date and the others properties? Is it possible to set Locale in french format and to change only the decimal separator to point (.)?

The problem I want to solve is the following :
I want to call a PL/SQL procedure from java with jdbcTemplate and with float and date parameters. The database is set with point (.) as decimal separator and comma for group. The java application is set with default Locale to french (fr_FR). But when executing the application an error is raised in the PL/SQL procedure because the decimal separators are not the same. The date format is the same in the database and in the java application. I can not change the database settings. How can I do to execute the PL/SQL procedure without errors ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: You can specify a format explicitly (eg. without using a default Locale) at the parse site.

Comment: I would recommend to use the proper locale for your `NumberFormat` and your `DateFormat` instances instead of changing the default `Locale`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to manipulate the default `Locale` every time you want to format something.  Both the `NumberFormat` class and the `DateFormat` class have static methods for obtaining numeric and date formatters in a specific locale.

For `NumberFormat`, use [the `getNumberInstance` method that takes a `Locale` as a parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance-java.util.Locale-).

```
double value = 123456.45;
NumberFormat english = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("en", "US"));
System.out.println(english.format(value));
```

Output:

```
123,456.45
```

For `DateFormat`, use [the `getDateInstance` method that takes a `Locale` as a parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance-int-java.util.Locale-).

```
Date now = new Date();
DateFormat french = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, new Locale("fr", "FR"));
System.out.println(french.format(now));
```

Output:

```
30 mars 2015
```

Comment: The problem is elsewhere in fact, with a database connection. The oracle database in set with point (.) as decimal separator and a comma (,) for the group. The Locale is set to french. When sending float and date parameters from java application to an oracle pl/sql procedure with jdbcTemplate, the float parameter raises an error in the pl/sql procedure because of the two different decimal formats. Will your solution fix the problem ?

Comment: @IntegraleOne Aha, an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don't you reformulate your top question to say what your *real* problem is? And add the appropriate tags. People who understand Spring and Oracle would help you better.

Comment: Is it possible to create its own Locale ? By example, by copying the French one and after setting the decimal separator with a dot (".") ?